# Negative index for array in cpp

Tags: c++

while browsing through a queue examples, I came across

http://login2win.blogspot.in/2008/07/c-queues.html

Its a queue example in which the indexes start from -1, but the program seems to be working fine

Is this valid, shouldn't this be a undefined behavior in some cases?

Comment: Which one of the 3 examples did you use? Arrays, linked list or stl?

Comment: Oh. Yes, it's UB indeed.

Comment: Another line is `rear = ++rear % MAX_SIZE;` which is also UB. Please don't use that code at all!

Comment: I'd advise finding a different tutorial. You apparently already know more than the author...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct. This code is invalid because it is dereferencing memory outside of that array.